# How to Overwrite or Refresh javascript setTimeout

Tags: javascript, refresh, settimeout

I need to refresh or overwrite setTimeout delay value.. I have a product quantity update button:

```
<q-input class="q-pb-none" v-model="quantity" dense borderless style="width: 25px" mask="###" @input="updateQty" />
<div class="col-auto">
          <div class="row"><q-icon name="keyboard_arrow_up" @click="quantity++" class="cursor-pointer"/></div>
          <div class="row"><q-icon name="keyboard_arrow_down" @click="quantity--" class="cursor-pointer"/></div>
        </div>
```

I don't want to make update request on every clicking of qty change buttons, instead of this following updateQty function should run 3 seconds later then user give up to click the button.

```
updateQty () {
// I need to refresh this timeout at evertime this function called.
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch('pack/updateProductQty')
      }, 3000)
    }
```

How can I set this logic? I use quasar vue.js framework. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the timeout id into a variable and clear the timeout on each click:

```
let timeoutId;

updateQty () {
    if (timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch('pack/updateProductQty')
    }, 3000)
}
```

IMHO a cleaner solution would be using Observables or similar technique.

Comment: Thank you. I've been go crazy almost.. I defined timeOutId variable just under  `<script>`tag in vue.js strcuture and it's solved. Thanks again.